# Transit visa London Heathrow needed?

Tags: visas, uk, transit, paperwork, venezuelan-citizens

If you have a Venezuelan passport, and if you have a Belgium residence permit and are married to a Dutch man, do you need a transit visa when you change planes in London on your return trip to Amsterdam? UK border check will be done in between flights.

If I check the government site, I think it is not necessary because of the Belgium residence permit. Am I right? It's not all clear to me.

Comment: Why would you need to go through UK border checks? Heathrow supports immigration-free transit even between terminals.

Comment: If you are married to a Dutch man and can prove it and he's travelling with you, you don't need any visa. You can even settle in the UK and work there with him if you wanted to.  All the perks until Brexit happens. ☺️

Answer (score 3):

No, with a Belgian residence permit, you don't need a visa, even if you have to collect and re-check luggage.